# capture photo with camera in cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova, netbeans, camera

I continue my training on cordova and javascript (i need it). 
I try to create a very little application using camera. For that i have take the code provide below
[http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera]
and i'm trying to adapt this code in a cordova project in netbeans.

i get the code below. I provide my index.html and my index.js. 
i have a problem when i test in the emulator. When i click on the button, nothing happened, there is not error message, nothing and obviously it take not picture with camera. it seem there is a problem with the line in the method capturePhoto because i have a warning in netbeans (global variable destinationType is not declared). Could you help me please ?

index.html

```
<head>     
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="myBtn">Capture Photo</button> <br>

    <img style="display:none;width:80px;height:80px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

    <script>
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", capturePhoto());
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js

```
 var app = {

    pictureSource:  "",  
    destinationType: "", 

    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler

    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        app.pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        app.destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    onPhotoDataSuccess: function(imageData) {
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    },

    // A button will call this function
    capturePhoto: function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    },

    // Called if something bad happens.
    onFail: function(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }


};

app.initialize();
```

thanks again by advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `navigator.camera.getPicture`, you want `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` rather than `destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL`. You should also specify the sourceType and mediaType, so you might want to do something like this:

```
function capturePhoto() {
    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, options);
}
```

Comment: it's the same. Now i have a warning and it says 
`the global variable camera is not declared` 
I 'm trying to modify my code to find a solution, there is many quirks i have to understand...

Comment: A couple of things: Cordova does not include any plugins, so you need to add whichever ones you want to use. Have you added the Camera plugin? So "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera" at the command line. Also, on rereading your post, I see you are trying to use the camera from within the emulator. AFAIK, the camera (and most other device hardware) is not available in the emulator.

Comment: hi Mike, Yes i added plugin. I think it's ok for that. And if i  i use the javasciprt code provide in cordova documentation (without any change), it's work even in the emulator. In this case emulator ask me to use the webcam of my computer and the application works fine. But problems arrive when i try to adapt this code (see the link above) in a cordova netbeans project. In this case i put my code in the index.js with many adaptations. I thinks it's more a lack of skills in javascript than a specific cordova problem misunderstood but i'm not sure...

Comment: Ok now after 2 days of research i think i found the source of my problem.  I don't know again how resolve it. The code i provide above has changed a little bit but my problem is always the same. My javascript code has a problem.
I get an error wheh i emulate my application. 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined (17:44:43:779 | error, javascript)
    at app.onDeviceReady (www/js/index.js:32:41)
    at (anonymous function) (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:227:34)`
It's like he didn't find the cordova.js however he is there. Camera plugin is added.

Comment: if someone would like to help to understand my mistake ...

`git@github.com:jermartin/myFirstMobileApp.git`
there is 2 branches, same code ... 
one for netbeans 
one for sublimetext
thanks for your help